# How create a row-level policy for purposes of using a new_user_id as a fk entry to another table

Tags: postgresql, insert, row-level-security

I have row-level security enabled on my `users` table. The table is part of a `core` schema.  I have the following policy that provides access by the `api` user:

```sql
create policy "Api(public) can view record when id=current_user_id"
    on core.users
    for all
    to api
    using(current_user_id() = id)
    with check (true);
```

However, the following procedure/function to register a new user violates the row-level security.

```sql
create or replace
function api.register(
    auth_agent core.auth_agent,
    auth_id text,
    email text
)
returns void as $$
    declare
        new_user_id uuid;
    begin
        raise info ' api.register: %', current_user;
        -- create a new users record
        insert into core.users (email)
        values (register.email)
        returning id into new_user_id; -- << Error causing

        -- create a new entry in the auth_ids_link_user
        insert into core.auth_ids_link_user (auth_agent, auth_id, user_id)
        values (auth_agent, auth_id, new_user_id);

        -- login using the new record
        perform api.login(auth_agent, auth_id);
    end;
$$ security definer language plpgsql;
```

... the error:

```sql
new row violates row-level security policy for table "users"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into core.users (email)
        values (register.email)
```

What is the the correct policy that

1. allows the api only to view the row/record where id = current_user_id()
2. lets the api use the core.users.id value to insert a new record in a table that uses the id as a fk

Thank you in advance to providing where there is surely an "idiomatic" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createpolicy.html) (read once more now with the clear question in mind), both the `insert` and `select` policies are read by postgres when using the `insert ... returning` command combination.

The following policies did the trick:

```sql
--  using with check for new records
create policy "Api can insert"
    on core.users
    for insert
    to api
    with check (true);

--  using using for existing records
create policy "Api can select (before current_user is set)"
    on core.users
    for select
    to api
    using (true);

create policy "Api can do anything when current_user_id"
    on core.users
    for all   -- where overlaps with other policies, think "or"
    to api
    using(current_user_id() = id)
    with check (current_user_id() = id);
```

Note: I had tried something similar prior to drafting this post, but only succeeded this-time-round by properly using `using` and `with check`.  The former is specific to *new* records (i.e., used in insert and update commands), while the latter is specific to *existing* records (i.e., used for select and delete commands).

Comment: But as it is used as a OR, does that mean that it will always pass, because of the first policy?

Comment: @JohnWinston A thoroughly delayed reply. Nonetheless, it is a good question that I hope this addresses. The grant of `all` is only provided when the current user is accessing their own record.